# How to best deploy SNMP in existing application?

Tags: c++, windows, snmp, net-snmp

I have an existing Windows desktop application written in C++ that needs to add support for SNMP so that a few pieces of status information are available on some SNMP OIDs. I found the [net-snmp](http://www.net-snmp.org) project and have been trying to understand how this can best fit into the existing program.

Questions:

1. Do I need to run snmpd, or can I just integrate the agent code into my application?  I would prefer that starting my application does everything necessary rather than worry about deploying and running multiple processes, but the documentation doesn't speak much about doing this.  The net-snmp agent daemon tutorial has an option for running the sample code as the full-agent rather than sub-agent, but I'm not sure about any limitations of doing this.
2. What would the PROs/CONs be for running a full agent in my application vs using snmpd and putting a subagent in my application? Is there a 3rd option I should also consider?
3. If I can integrate the full agent into the existing program, how do I pass it a configuration file via the API?  Can I avoid the config file all together by passing these parameters in via function call instead?

Comment: You'd better reveal more on "that needs to add support for SNMP so that a few pieces of status information are available on some SNMP OIDs". It is no more a best practice to expose status information via SNMP (better options are out there).

Comment: Agreed.   I would not go this route, but this is a customer requirement to work with legacy equipment that reads status via SNMP.